# Ordered LinkedList logic in Java, LinearNode head is being reassigned each time

Tags: java, list, generics, linked-list, logic

I have a generic ordered Linked List class. For some reason, LinearNode head is being reassigned every single time I run add(). Any ideas? Why would head be changed each time I run this? I'm not even touching it. I can provide the other classes for testing, if needed.

```
 public class myOrLiList<T extends Comparable<T>> {

public LinearNode head;
public int count;

public myOrLiList() {
    head = null;
    count = 0;

}

// LinearNode INNER CLASS
public class LinearNode {
    public LinearNode next;
    public T item;

    public LinearNode(T thisitem) {
        this.next = null;
        this.item = thisitem;
    }

}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}
public void add(T thisItem) {

    LinearNode newNode = new LinearNode(thisItem);

    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = newNode;
        System.out.println("head filled!");
    } else {
        LinearNode compareNode = head;
        do {
            if (thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) < 0) {
                newNode.next = compareNode;
                break;
            } else if ((thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) < 0)
                    || (thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) == 0)) {
                newNode.next = compareNode.next;
                compareNode.next = newNode;
                break;
            } else {
                compareNode = compareNode.next;
            }
        } while (compareNode.next != null);
    }
    System.out.println("Added!");
    count++;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What will happen if `thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item)` is larger than any element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this class has some errors (Thanks for the tips, Michael!) the question I asked did not come from these errors.

In the new object class I had created for T, I had declared static properties. So, each time a new T thisItem was being created, all of the properties of all objects were being changed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your `head` is changing is because of this line:

```
compareNode = compareNode.next;
```

Earlier you did this:

```
LinearNode compareNode = head;
```

You're literally saying that `compareNode` IS your head object. You're setting the Object reference that points to head to also point to `compareNode`. Any actions you take on `compareNode` will affect `head` the exact same way.

Because you set compareNode = head, these two lines do the same thing to the same object reference:

```
compareNode.next = null;
head.next = null;
```

I see a couple of other things wrong. I'll try and go over them one by one.

Your logic for when the `LinkedList` is empty appears to be correct...

However,

if you add a second node when the list's size is 1, you're going to have some problems...

`if (thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) < 0)` you call this code and then break out:

```
newNode.next = compareNode;
break;
```

What are you doing with newNode after that? The answer is nothing. Since you didn't update `head`, nothing has changed. You created a `LinearNode`, set it's `next` value equal to the `head`, and then left it to die.

What I think you want to do is get a reference to the old node stored at `head`, save it, then set your `head` variable equal to your new node. Then you'll set newNode.next (where `newNode` is now `head`) equal to your OLD head node, which you saved. So you'll have something like this:

```
LinearNode oldHead = head;
head = newNode;
head.next = oldHead;
```

Now for the next part. You have an

```
if ((thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) < 0) || (thisItem.compareTo(compareNode.item) == 0))
```

You already covered the case where `compareNode.item < 0`, so why are you checking it again? It won't mess up your logic, but it's redundant.

Essentially, what you're trying to do is place your newNode before the current node if it compares to be < 0, place your newNode after the current node if it compares to be > 0, and either replace or do nothing if the currentElement ends up being == 0.

I've covered the < 0 case, so you should try and figure out how to do the greater than and equal cases.

Comment: @babybunnies Well? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks so much. The reason the head was changing each time was because of objects declared static in another class. But thanks for the other tips!